# How do I automatically get the list of all the collections from my Document DB from AWS GLUE?

Tags: mongodb, etl, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

Here's what I want to Achieve:

1. Connect to my Document DB cluster.
2. Connect to a particular Database inside the cluster.
3. Get the list of all the collections (tables) inside that particular DB.
4. Extract 500 rows of data from all the tables.
5. Export each table as a .csv file and store it a s3 Bucket.

Now the problem is a lot of information has to be hardcoded like for example the collection name while creating the crawler -
[image]

I cannot possibly do this for all the collections in that DB.
How Do I automate the process?

What I've tried so far:
I've done this for a single collection using AWS glue-
Step 1 - created a custom connector.
Step 2- Created a crawler from the connection and got the schema of the table.
Step 3- created an ETL job from the data catalog and ran a script which extracts 500 rows and exports it in the .csv format and uploads it into another s3 Bucket.

Script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

read_mongo_options = {
"uri": "mongodb://docdb-xyz.ap-south-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017",
"database": "test",
"collection": "collectionname",
"username": "user",
"ssl": "true",
"password": "password123"
}


# Script generated for node Data Catalog table
DataCatalogtable_node1 = glueContext.create_sample_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="mongodb",
    connection_options=read_mongo_options,
    num=500,
    transformation_ctx="DataCatalogtable_node1"
)
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame = DataCatalogtable_node1, 
    mappings=[
        ("account number", "long", "account number", "long"),
        ("cust_sensitivity", "string", "cust_sensitivity", "string"),
        ("pan number", "string", "pan number", "string"),
        ("cust_loyalty_points", "int", "cust_loyalty_points", "int"),
        ("graduation_yrof_ind", "int", "graduation_yrof_ind", "int"),
        ("gender", "string", "gender", "string"),
        ("aadhaar_card_number", "double", "aadhaar_card_number", "double"),
        ("no_of_2_wheelers_owned", "int", "no_of_2_wheelers_owned", "int"),
        (
            "mi_is_betterthan_competition",
            "string",
            "mi_is_betterthan_competition",
            "string",
        ),
        ("degree_pref_mulcar_family", "int", "degree_pref_mulcar_family", "int"),
        ("cust_retention_overall", "int", "cust_retention_overall", "int"),
        ("complaints_cnt", "int", "complaints_cnt", "int"),
        ("no_of_dependents", "int", "no_of_dependents", "int"),
        ("family_member_cnt", "int", "family_member_cnt", "int"),
        ("cust_retention_sale", "int", "cust_retention_sale", "int"),
        ("complaints_open_cnt", "int", "complaints_open_cnt", "int"),
        (
            "upsell_crosssell_opportunity",
            "string",
            "upsell_crosssell_opportunity",
            "string",
        ),
        ("cust_segment", "string", "cust_segment", "string"),
        ("purpose_of_vehicle", "string", "purpose_of_vehicle", "string"),
        ("yrof_1st_job_after_grad", "int", "yrof_1st_job_after_grad", "int"),
        ("tot_mul_cars_owned_family", "int", "tot_mul_cars_owned_family", "int"),
        ("marital-status", "string", "marital-status", "string"),
        ("cust_mhi_sale", "int", "cust_mhi_sale", "int"),
        ("no_of_earning_members", "int", "no_of_earning_members", "int"),
        ("become_parent_last_1st_yr", "string", "become_parent_last_1st_yr", "string"),
        ("no_of_children", "int", "no_of_children", "int"),
        ("zipcode", "int", "zipcode", "int"),
        ("cust_mood", "string", "cust_mood", "string"),
        ("cust_type", "string", "cust_type", "string"),
        ("average_household_savings", "int", "average_household_savings", "int"),
        ("tot_nonmul_cars_owned_family", "int", "tot_nonmul_cars_owned_family", "int"),
        (
            "didyou_evenbuy_nonmi_for_veh",
            "string",
            "didyou_evenbuy_nonmi_for_veh",
            "string",
        ),
        ("occupation", "string", "occupation", "string"),
        ("date of birth", "string", "date of birth", "string"),
        ("dob_children1", "string", "dob_children1", "string"),
        ("_id", "struct", "_id", "string"),
        ("email-id", "string", "email-id", "string"),
        ("tot_cars_owned_family", "int", "tot_cars_owned_family", "int"),
        ("dob_children2", "string", "dob_children2", "string"),
        ("svoc_id", "string", "svoc_id", "string"),
        ("mobile_number", "long", "mobile_number", "long"),
        ("cust_tot_clv", "int", "cust_tot_clv", "int"),
        ("personal_annual_income", "int", "personal_annual_income", "int"),
        ("cust_name", "string", "cust_name", "string"),
        ("location", "string", "location", "string"),
    ], 
    transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"
 )
 
dyf_repartion = applymapping1.coalesce(1)
 
# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dyf_repartion,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://ouputbucket", "partitionKeys": []},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: What did not work?   Seems like the answer is in the question...?